# Is there a way to iterate through a Codable (e.g. each item in a JSON parse)?

Tags: swift, codable, introspection

Say you're decoding a huge JSON file:

```
struct Examp: Codable {
  let Cats: [CatsItem]
  let Dogs: [DogsItem]
  let Horses: [HorsesItem]
  .. forty more
}
```

After you parse it, on the console you simply want to see how many of each:

```
print("cats .. \(result.Cats.count)")
print("dogs .. \(result.Dogs.count)")
```

and so on, the result being cats 1,015, dogs 932, etc.

I'm too lazy to repeatedly type a line of code like this:

```
print("cats .. \(result.Cats.count)")
```

Without having to modify `Examp` in any way, is there a way to do something like:

```
for (thing) in Examp { print("\(thing string) .. \(result.(thing).count)") }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `Mirror` to reflect on the `Examp`, and loop through its children. You can then print the name and value of each child. To get the array's size, you can cast the value to `[Any]`, since arrays are covariant (any type of array can be casted to `[Any]`).

For example:

```
struct Example: Codable {
    let cats: [String]
    let dogs: [String]
    let horses: [String]
}

let example = Example(cats: [""], dogs: ["", ""], horses: ["", "", ""])
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: example)
for (name, value) in mirror.children {
    guard let name, let array = value as? [Any] else { continue }
    print("\(name) .. \(array.count)")
}
```